# How to set the same size of a set of selected objects in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I have many objects of different sizes in Inkscape, and I need to transform them to the right size. Manually resizing each object takes too much time. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to menu Object → Transform (or hit Shift + Ctrl + M by default) and make sure you have *Apply to each object separately* option enabled – see the picture:

[image: inkscape transform menu]

Answer (score 16):

Another option:

If you have one object that already has the size you want:

- copy it
- then select the other objects that you want to have that same size
- and do Edit > Paste size > Paste size separately

If you want to keep the aspect ratio, click the lock icon in the select tool's tool bar before pasting either 'width separately', or 'height separately'.

Comment: wow, that was amazing.  I had a bunch of circles, some 0.499 by 0.501 etc etc.  I wanted all to be 0.5 by 0.5 exactly.  This nailed it.

Comment: Oh, and just as an added bonus, this kept the circles in the same exact center point.  Just what I wanted.  If you manually change sizes the have to be realigned